# html form onselection change value of drop down field

Tags: html

My form contain to radio buttons for timestamp namely `LOT` and `UTC`.
Default value selected is UTC. My drop-down contain gmt offset value and name.
i.e

> ```
> <select name="DropDownTimezone" id="DropDownTimezone" onchange="">
>     <opetion value="5">(GMT +5:30) Bombay, Calcutta, Madras, New Delhi</option>
>     <option value="6">(GMT +5:00) Ekaterinburg, Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent</option>
>     <opetion value="7">(GMT) Western Europe Time, London, Lisbon, Casablanca<option>
>     ..
>     ...
>     .
>     etc.
> </select>
> ```

I have to set default value bombay when I choose LOT and when choose UTC then default value set for London. How we can set this on html form?
Please give me some simple logic.?

```
 <input type="radio"  id="DateTimeZone1" onchange="" 
 name="DateTimeZoneID" value="2">LOT  <input type="radio" 
 id="DateTimeZone2" onchange="" name="DateTimeZoneID" value="2">UTC
```

Comment: You will need javascript/jQuery to achieve this. Include the complete code for your radios and select, or better yet create a fiddle.

Comment: OK @Ted see check edit code update again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hm6qzd9/1/), here's the relevant code from it, in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio[name ="DateTimeZoneID"]').change(function(e){
        var radioVal = $('input:radio[name ="DateTimeZoneID"]:checked').val();
        if(radioVal == 1){
            $("#DropDownTimezone").val('8');// whatever the options val is
        }else if(radioVal == 2){
            $("#DropDownTimezone").val('9.9');// whatever the options val is
        }
    });
});
```

**also** on a side note, make sure to fix the typos in your code, like `<opetion` etc

just fyi in case you're not familiar with jQuery--you'll need to include jquery as well, add this to the head:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please just tell me in this code what is radioVal and .val. I did not get this.

Comment: take a look at the demo... the `var radioVal` is getting the value of the selected radio button. `$.val()` is used to either set or get the value of a control. Keep in mind, this is a jQuery solution.

Comment: I have to written this in jquery meance in script right?.

Comment: Yes, you need to include jquery and wrap that in a doc ready function--I'll update the code in the answer

Comment: problem is there. My from default selected UTC and default dropdown london..and my dropdown values are in float i.e for london (0.0) for bobay (5.5) etc. so,LOT selection It takes right i.e. bombay but UTC it takes first value of dropdown why?

Comment: set the vals as strings. I updated the code in the answer, and the linked demo

Comment: No problem, glad to be of service

Comment: Hey @ Ted are you there? I ahve one query is that if I want it viseversa then same logic? i.e. If I choose london dorpdown then check box will set to UTC?